# Change color font of a Sankey Diagram with `networkD3`

Tags: r, networkd3

I want to chanche color fonts, or add a shadow in font in order to improve visibility. However I haven't found a way to do it. One alternative is to use plotly, but when you put a plotly object in a shiny app and visualize it in a mobile phone, you lose interactive labels, so networkD3 shoes a better integration. The only problem is That I'm having dificulties to personalize appareance. I want to change font color.

A reprodutible example:

```
library(networkD3)
URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
              'master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

# Plot
sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
              Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
              units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text elements can be modifying my adding an `onRender` script from the package `htmlwidgets`. This function allows you to run additional javascript functions for selecting and modifying elements using D3. The structure of the function is:

```r
p <- onRender(myplot,'function(el, x){ 
    ...
}')
```

Using the example, you can select labels using `d3.selectAll` (this returns every element; use `d3.select()` for single element or the first element only).

```js
// Sankey selector for node labels
d3.selectAll(".node text")
```

Modifying the color of a `<text>` element can be done using `style('some prop', 'some value')`. For example, let's say we want to change the text to `blue`.

```js
d3.selectAll(".node text").style("fill", "blue") // or hex, rgb, hsl, etc.
```

Using your example above, here's how you could write it.

```r
library(networkD3)
URL <- 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json'
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

# Plot
sankey <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
  Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
  units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30
)

# render with js
sankey_rendered <- htmlwidgets::onRender(sankey,
  'function(el, x) {
    d3.selectAll(".node text")
        .style("fill", "blue");
  }'
)

# show
sankey_rendered
```

If you would like to do more with the labels (i.e., mouse events, clicks), assign the D3 select result to a variable.

```js
var labels = d3.selectAll(".node text");
```

Comment: This way indeed changed font color, but led to lose pupups. Con I get change color an preserve popups?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What popups are you referring to?

Comment: forgetit I just nedeed restart my r session.Just the labels that appear when put mouse on a node or link